# Inserting into two mysql tables using join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with one to one relationship. (ID Column) Is it possible to use **JOIN** and **INSERT** together, to insert into both tables in one query? I researched but couldn't find what i am expecting. FYI I am using MySQL 5.7.

Thanks.

Comment: No. You can only insert into one table at a time.

Comment: Argh. Thats disappointing. So it means i have to add them both using two queries or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Not 2 queries that is twice the amount of work, ahhhh why can't it be done with just 1 this is far too much work :)

Comment: Hehe Toby point taken :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the docs are concerned, you can make a view and use that for inserting into an 1-to-1 relationship.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-updatability.html

**.....EDIT........**

Alas, inserts are only allowed into one of the joined tables:

"For a multiple-table updatable view, INSERT can work if it inserts into a single table."

So you will have to make 2 statements.

Comment: Same as with a table